# SQL Server 2008 import asymmetric keys from file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, public-key-encryption

I've generated a pair of asymmetric keys in my Linux box. Now I want to import them into SQL Server with:

```
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY fi2 
    FROM FILE = 'c:\keys\public_key.pem'
```

I always get the error:

> The certificate, asymmetric key, or private key file does not exist or has invalid format.

Any clues on the format the file must have to be imported?